# Actions of sets endowed with algebraic structures

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In algebra/linear algebra we learn how to construct actions of sets endowed with specific algebraic structures on other sets. So for example, in the theory of vector spaces we have an action of a field or a skew-field. In the theory of $R$-modules we have a ring action, and in $G$-sets a group action.

I am wondering if there exist other types of 'actions' of algebraic structures in this sense. Can anyone provide examples or suggest theoretical frames where to look into?

Comment: If you look up what a "monoid object" in a category is, and then what it means to be a "module over a monoid object", that encompasses all of the examples you have above, except perhaps vector spaces (I think that you have to start out with vector spaces or Z-modules, but perhaps someone more categorically inclined can correct me).